# How to create ole's OBShapedButton programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios

In project i have to create number of non regular buttons.on net , i found the ole's  OBShapedButton .It is nice project and all work done from xib.I have to create it programatically .But its not working.I do following steps.

1.Add OBShapedButton.h, OBShapedButton.m, UIImage+ColorAtPixel.h, and UIImage+ColorAtPixel.m to your Xcode project.
2.in view controller create object of  OBShapedButton.

```
 obj_OBShapedButton=[[OBShapedButton alloc]init];
 obj_OBShapedButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 [obj_OBShapedButton setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 160,161)];

[obj_OBShapedButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button-normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[obj_OBShapedButton addTarget:self action:@selector(Buton_action) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.view addSubview:obj_OBShapedButton];
```

It displays an irregular shape button .

Problem here is whole button frame take click , and  not accept only click on image ….does anyone try to do ole's  OBShapedButton programatically..

Plz let me know.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are first creating an instance of `OBShapedButton` then replace it with an instance of `UIButton`.
Remove the `obj_OBShapedButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]`, since you already have an object assigned to `obj_OBShapedButton`

The code will be like this:

```
obj_OBShapedButton = [OBShapedButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[obj_OBShapedButton setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 160,161)];

[obj_OBShapedButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button-normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[obj_OBShapedButton addTarget:self action:@selector(Buton_action) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.view addSubview:obj_OBShapedButton];
```